# go slice address in memory

Tags: go, slice, padding

I ran the following code on 64-bits OS and got the result that the difference between each slice's address is 32Byte(`0xc42008a060 - 0xc42008a040` `0xc42008a040 - 0xc42008a020`). I guess it should be 24Byte, because the size of slice is 24B and the align is 8. Just like the example of int64.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)
func main() {
    var sl1 []int
    var sl2 []int
    var sl3 []int
    fmt.Printf("slice:\n")
    fmt.Printf("sl1 addr %p, align %d, size %d\n", &sl1, unsafe.Alignof(sl1), unsafe.Sizeof(sl1))
    fmt.Printf("sl1 addr %p, align %d, size %d\n", &sl2, unsafe.Alignof(sl2), unsafe.Sizeof(sl2))
    fmt.Printf("sl1 addr %p, align %d, size %d\n", &sl3, unsafe.Alignof(sl3), unsafe.Sizeof(sl3))

    var i1 int
    var i2 int
    var i3 int
    fmt.Printf("int:\n")
    fmt.Printf("i1 addr %p, align %d, size %d\n", &i1, unsafe.Alignof(i1), unsafe.Sizeof(i1))
    fmt.Printf("i2 addr %p, align %d, size %d\n", &i2, unsafe.Alignof(i2), unsafe.Sizeof(i2))
    fmt.Printf("i3 addr %p, align %d, size %d\n", &i3, unsafe.Alignof(i3), unsafe.Sizeof(i3))
}
```

output:

```
slice:
slice:
sl1 addr 0xc42008a020, align 8, size 24
sl1 addr 0xc42008a040, align 8, size 24
sl1 addr 0xc42008a060, align 8, size 24
int:
i1 addr 0xc42007c020, align 8, size 8
i2 addr 0xc42007c028, align 8, size 8
i3 addr 0xc42007c030, align 8, size 8
```

At first I guess there might be something else occupied the extra 8B, and  then I rerun it many time and the addresses are changed sometime when I modify a few codes, but I always found the difference was 32B or bigger. I just know a little about slice and struct padding and very confused about it. Can anyone help me. Many thanks

-------update another test-----

I print the value via point just like

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {

    arr := [5]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    s1 := arr[0:1]
    s2 := arr[0:2]

    fmt.Printf("arr addr %p\n", &arr)
    fmt.Printf("s1 addr %p, align %d, size %d\n", &s1, unsafe.Alignof(s1), unsafe.Sizeof(s1))
    fmt.Printf("s2 addr %p, align %d, size %d\n", &s2, unsafe.Alignof(s2), unsafe.Sizeof(s2))

    //var spInt *int64 = (*int64)(unsafe.Pointer(sp))
    fmt.Printf("\ns1:\n")
    sp := &s1
    fmt.Printf("address: %v\n",     unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(sp))))
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("+ 0(arr): 0x%x", *(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(sp))))))
    fmt.Printf("+ 8(len): %d\n", *(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(sp)) + uintptr(8))))
    fmt.Printf("+16(cap): %d\n", *(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(sp)) + uintptr(16))))
    fmt.Printf("+24(unknow): %d\n", *(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(sp)) + uintptr(24))))

    fmt.Printf("\ns2:\n")
    sp = &s2
    fmt.Printf("address: %v\n", unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(sp))))
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("+ 0(arr): 0x%x", *(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(sp))))))
    fmt.Printf("+ 8(len): %d\n", *(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(sp)) + uintptr(8))))
    fmt.Printf("+16(cap): %d\n", *(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(sp)) + uintptr(16))))
    fmt.Printf("+24(unknow): %d\n\n", *(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(sp)) + uintptr(24))))
}
```

and I get the result:

```
arr addr 0xc420018150
s1 addr 0xc42000a060, align 8, size 24
s2 addr 0xc42000a080, align 8, size 24

s1:
address: 0xc42000a060
+ 0(arr): 0xc420018150
+ 8(len): 1
+16(cap): 5
+24(unknow): 0

s2:
address: 0xc42000a080
+ 0(arr): 0xc420018150
+ 8(len): 2
+16(cap): 5
+24(unknow): 0
```

The first 8B is the address of data array, the second is the length of slice and the third is capacity of slice. But the last 8B seems to be empty. What the last 8B is used for? For padding?

Comment: Why do you think it should be 24 bytes? Your assumptions are a) wrong and b) not justified by the language spec.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate your assumptions with the project [`tyranron/golang-sizeof.tips`](https://github.com/tyranron/golang-sizeof.tips) and its online page *was* at [**golang-sizeof.tips**](https://web.archive.org/web/20190720050820/http://golang-sizeof.tips/) (back in 2018/2019):

The size is as expected.
But the [`atomic` package does mention](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#pkg-note-BUG):

> The first word in a variable or in an allocated struct, array, or slice can be relied upon to be 64-bit aligned.

See <del>[this thread](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/golang-nuts/157skxmvep/go-nuts-sync-atomic-64-bit-alignment)</del> (also referenced in [`golang/go` issue 11891](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11891)):

> The quote is "The first word in a global variable or in an allocated
> struct or slice can be relied upon to be 64-bit aligned."
> The key phrase there is "**allocated**", not "struct or slice."
>
> The first word in a struct or slice that is allocated via new or via a composite literal will be 64-bit aligned.
> A struct inside a slice or array is not allocated by itself, and no particular alignment is guaranteed beyond that of `unsafe.AlignOf`.

Comment: http://golang-sizeof.tips/?t=Ly8gU2FtcGxlIGNvZGUKc3RydWN0IHsKCXNsMiBbXWludAp9Cg== the size of slice is 24B and it seems there is no padding. I try to print the last 8B and get empty just like question's update. So what last 8B is used for?

Comment: @user2256235 there might not be alignment within the same structure (although https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19057 advocate for a more visible alignment), but there could be still alignments between tow variables allocated on the head.

Comment: Is there any introduction about alignments between variables? I just search on google but did found few related things.

Comment: The link to the .tips domain now contains spam and potentially nasty drive-by stuff and is blocked by adblocker lists. Please remove the link, the project is archived, the online site potentially dangerous.

Comment: @TheDiveO Thank you for the update. I have edited the answer accordingly.